# Application stop suddenly and getting NSURLErrorDomain error

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, centos, ios13.3

I am using IOS 13.3 and my application stop suddenly after 6 month.
I have checked my certificate and found no issue in certificate.

i am getting the following error.

```
 NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9816)
2020-04-17 01:38:14.778140+0530 Example[38000:704335] Task <71350D43-9801-46F2-9F9E-333AF09964CE>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9816])
2020-04-17 01:38:14.779009+0530 Example[38000:704332] Task <71350D43-9801-46F2-9F9E-333AF09964CE>.<1> finished with error - code: -1200
2020-04-17 01:38:14.782985+0530 Example[38000:704332] Task <71350D43-9801-46F2-9F9E-333AF09964CE>.<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.example.com:1410/v1.1/users/signin, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <71350D43-9801-46F2-9F9E-333AF09964CE>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <71350D43-9801-46F2-9F9E-333AF09964CE>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.example.com:1410/v1.1/users/signin, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002db3d50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9816, kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816}}, kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816} [-1200]
```

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

I'm not sure how to solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your server support TLS 1.3 and forward secrecy?  -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307698/apple-doesnt-recognize-imgurs-https

Comment: @Paulw11 No, Do we need to change on sever or app level? If Yes then How

Comment: The best thing is top upgrade your server software so that it supports the improved security. If you can't then you can add an exception to the ATS settings in your info.plist to make iOS ignore the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to reconfigure your SSL certificates. I know for TCP/TLS at least, with iOS 13 they imposed more restrictions on the certificates. I created a package to handle sockets on iOS - I also included a lot of good info about making certificates how you need to now.

https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets/tree/master